# Rho meson decay to three neutral pions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, conservation-laws, standard-model, pions

In my assignment, I am asked to show whether $\rho^0\to3\pi^0$ is allowed. From the particle data group, I cannot find the decay mode; hence, I am guessing it is not allowed. Based on the knowledge that $\rho^0\to2\pi^0$ is not allowed, I focus on parity. However, the action contains an angular momentum of 3 bodies. Then I get stuck. Can someone tell me whether this action is allowed? Or at least give me some hint. (I have not learned weak interaction and strong interaction yet.)

Comment: Well, the decay certainly  violates G-parity, but so does the suppressed but allowed decay $\pi^0\pi^-\pi^+$, since isospin is an imperfect symmetry, hence also G. Parity violation would make the decay weak, so enormously suppressed. Note your 3-body wf must be completely symmetric, but, can it be?

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yes, my question now becomes for many bodies (or 3 bodies) problem, will the orbital angular momentum still have the same spherical harmonic function? If so, then the $Y_1^m$ will change the sign under parity; hence, 3 $\pi^0$ cannot be in the same orbit because they are indistinguishable.

Answer (score 1):

I confess I might be overthinking this, having missed something more obvious (C? -- violated by the weak interactions).

The G-parity of the ρ is +, so it prefers to decay to 2π s, since the π has G parity -. (It requires an antisymmetric state because of angular momentum, as you already see.)

But G-parity relies on isospin, which is broken somewhat in the strong decay, so there is also the 3π  mode at the $10^{-4}$ level, where all 3π s are different, instead of your 3π<sup>0</sup> which *has* to be fully symmetric.

You cannot first combine the two π<sup>0</sup>s to a vector by an L=1 as you notice, by their unavoidable symmetry. So you have to combine them to a symmetric S-wave spinless neutral dipion, and *then* combine that antisymmetrically with an L=1 to the remaining neutral π<sup>0</sup> to net a vector ρ<sup>0</sup>.

However, this is impossible; ignoring normalizations,
$$
(12+21)3-3(12+21)= 123+213-312-321= (123-321)+(-312+213),
$$
but the terms in the first and second final parentheses are 1-3 antisymmetric, and 3-2 antisymmetric respectively, which is impossible for identical neutral pions.

This argument fails, of course, (phew!),  for the extant decay mode π<sup>0</sup>π<sup>+</sup>π<sup>-</sup> which is allowed, although ferociously suppressed.